# Not sure if my HTML is limited to a single media file request using IE conditionals

Tags: html, bandwidth

I've been getting very high bandwidth consumption on my server and I was wondering if the following markup results in more information being requested than what is necessary. Is that the case or would this work as expected?

Here is my markup:

```
   <div id="video-container">
     <object class="video" height="100%" width="100%">
       <param name="movie" value="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.swf">
       <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
       <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
       <![if !IE]>
         <object class="video" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.swf" height="100%" width="100%">
            <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
            <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
         </object>
       <![endif]>
         <![if !IE]>
           <div class="video">
             <video class="video" height="100%" width="100%" autoplay loop >
               <source src="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.webm" type="video/webm">
               <source src="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.ogg" type="video/ogg">
             </video>                                
           </div>
         <![endif]-->
         <!--[if IE]>
           <div class="video" >
             <object class="video" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="100%" width="100%">
               <param name="src" value="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.mov">
               <param name="autoplay" value="true">
               <param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="100%" width="100%">
             </object>
           </div>
         <![endif]-->
       <![if !IE]>
         </object>
       <![endif]>
     </object>
    </div>



<audio id="audioplayer" autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.mp3">
    <source src="http://cutmeoffmidfunk.s3.amazonaws.com/bill.ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: In Chrome on Windows 7 it downloads multiple files. Probably due to your first set of conditional IE comments being malformed.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you posted seems to be malformed as thre are missing /> on some of the params. There is also an extra  tag for non ie browsers and your first and last set of conditional commens are malformed. I would fix those and then take a look at what the code does.

When correctly formed, your code and you are not in IE:

1. your code will load the bill.swf file for the outer object
2. it will then use the next object as well, which may or may not, depending on your cache settings cause bill.swf to be loaded again.
3. Then it will start loading the assets in the  sources. The browser may or may not decide to download all three files or just the one it needs.

When in IE:

1. your code will load the bill.swf file for the outer object
2. it will then use the next object as well, which may or may not, depending on your cache settings cause bill.swf to be loaded again.
3. Then it will start loading the assets in the third  declaration only.

Once you have fixed the HTML and made sure that the assests you are requesting are necessary and your desired outcome is achieved, if you are still experiencing high load, you may want to consider using a service like CloudFlair (I don't reccomend CloudFlair, although they are cheap as free on many cPanel hosts) in order to cache files and keep load off of the server itself. You may also want to look at the chache headers you set on served content to see if files that don't change that often can be set to cache for long periods of time so that they will only need to load once on each client and reduce server load.